# Problem deploying GWT project with a servlet that invoke an EJB

Tags: gwt

I have a simple GWT project in Eclipse, it has a servlet that calls an EJB and everything works fine when I run it in hosted mode from Eclipse.

MyProject
+- src
+- JRE System Library
+- GWT SDK
+- Apache Geronimo v2.2
+- myEJB.jar
+- openejb.jar
-- war
-- +- images
-- +- myproject
-- +- WEB-INF

I'm not sure what is the best way to deploy it, but what I did is create a .war file from the "war" folder of the project then deploy it to the server.

Communication between client and server works fine but I get
an error when I try to do JNDI look up for the EJB within the servlet.  The error I get is something like "JNDI error, cannot find FooManagerRemote"

Things works fine in hosted mode so I'm pretty sure that I din't deploy it correctly.

Comment: How do you look up the EJB in the servlet? Which name do you use? Can you inspect your console to find out under which name the EJB actually gets deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just missing classes in the EJB jar in MyProject's war/WEB-INF/lib/ folder.